# Any examples of currency name variations based on location on top of language?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization

I'm currently tackling the currency part of a PHP e-commerce plugin for a CMS I'm using and I have a question about localized currency names. I understand that currency names are said differently in different languages, for example:

Australian Dollar (English) and Dólar Australiano (Spanish)

...just like language names are said differently (Spanish vs Español), but I was wondering if there is any differences based on location as well? Ie, are there any countries/locations that speak the same language but would say a currency name differently?

Comment: Okay, and what's the question?

Comment: Pressed enter too soon. Sorry guys, no need to down vote for it!

Comment: My gut feeling says yes, probably. However, unless you want to support thousands of languages, probably not in one you want to support.

Comment: So with currency names, just support different languages and that's it? Don't worry if there is variances based on location. I'll keep the question open in case anyone can think of an obvious example where this happens, but otherwise if you want to put that as an answer and I can accept that.

Comment: Just make it language based should do for a most cases. Possibly base is on locale's though (i.e: nl_BE != nl_NL, and de_DE != de_AT). I see this with no authority whatsoever, hence the comment instead of an answer ;P

Comment: This question is on topic. Not sure why it was closed, but at least I got my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but rare, to have the same currency named differently in different versions of one language, according to country. Probably the best resource in matters of localized names for currencies is CLDR, see especially
http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/by_type/names.currency.html

For example, according to that data, the name of Aruban florin is “Florin de Aruba” in Portuguese generically (pt) but “Florim de Aruba” in Portuguese in Portugal (pt−PT). There are other small differences, caused by differences in Portuguese orthographies.

Comment: That's an incredible resource, thank you very much!!